# onActivityResult on tabwidget

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am new in android development. I am not getting call `onActivityResult` method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println("================================");
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
       Toast.makeText(TaskListActivity.this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else{
       Toast.makeText(TaskListActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: tip: don't use `System.out.println();` in android, use `Log.d()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Write down your code on Parent Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println("================================");
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
       Toast.makeText(TaskListActivity.this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else{
       Toast.makeText(TaskListActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

When You used tabwidget,you have to write onActivityResult on Parent  activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be using the `Log` class, not `System.out.println()`, to print to the logcat.
2. You forgot to call `super.onActivityResult()` at the end of the method.
3. Make sure you are starting the child activity with `startActivityForResult`. Be sure that the second argument you pass to it is a non-negative integer, or else `onActivityResult()` won't be called when the child activity finishes.